# OS upgrade from W-8.1 to W-10, boost fps?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I am facing a difficult situation, I have an "old" Toshiba laptop (L50-A-105) with a windows 8 OS, and I have been told that windows 10 is less of a "heavy load" on the system than windows 8, which might resault in better FPS in games,and  I have some questions which no one I know could answer:

1. Does the upgrade to windows 10 allow for better FPS in games than windows 8?
2. If I happen to upgrade to windows 10, will it wipe out all my stored files?
3. There are drivers for windows 10 upgrade for my pc on Toshiba's website, how do I apply them to my system exactly?, do I need to put them on a flashdrive and after I upgrade to windows 10 I will need to install them?

Comment: Might result in an improvement for games capable of using DirectX 12, and some at best marginal improvement in older games, possibly. I wouldn't upgrade just because I needed more performance as it is likely to be only a marginal improvement at best, probably the best improvement comes when you do a clean install and get rid of all the crapware in your current install.

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2949894/windows/windows-10-vs-windows-8-performance-benchmarks-show-a-close-battle-for-fastest.html

Comment: "will it wipe out all my stored files?" - Yes but only if you choose the "keep nothing" option.

Answer (score 0):

1. It could allow better frames per second in certain games.
2. It will keep your files if you are using the free install as long as you select something like keep my files.
3. I am not sure about the drivers just look it up before you upgrade if you upgrade.